# Full join between tsv files and column renaming based on file of origin

Tags: python, bash, dataframe

I have 176 `.tsv` files as a result of a gene alignment looking like these:

| target_id | length | tpm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ENST0001 | 12 | 100 |
| ENST0001 | 9 | 5 |

In these files, I expect a certain overlap between `target_id` columns but not complete, so I would like to do a full join and keep all rows. Additionally, I am interested in keeping only the tpm values of each file and rename the column according to the file name.

The expected dataframe would be something similar to:

| target_id | SRR100001 | SRR100002 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ENST0001 | 100 | 7 |
| ENST00015 | 5 | 0 |

I am aware of the `join` function in bash, but it can be used for two files per time and if I understood correctly I cannot select specific columns...

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: The files are named as SRR*.tsv

Comment: What's your directory structure look like? Files are called e.g. SRR100001.tsv?

Comment: That is correct. The pattern is SRR*.tsv. I will add it to my post for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this code works for you, it's hard to test without having the files.

```
import re
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd

tpm_dict = {}

for fn in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]):
    if re.match('.*\.tsv$', fn):
        header = fn.replace('.tsv', '')
        this_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(sys.argv[1], fn), sep='\t')
        for i, row in this_df.iterrows():
            try:
                tpm_dict[row['target_id']][header] = row['tpm']
            except KeyError:
                try:
                    tpm_dict[row['target_id']] = {header: row['tpm']}
                except:
                    print(f"Problem in {fn} at row {i}")

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tpm_dict, orient='index')
df.to_csv('joined.tsv', sep='\t')
```

Save as `tsvjoin.py` and then run `python3 tsvjoin.py <folder with TSVs>`

Edit: typos

Comment: Thanks Albert. I get however an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File SRR1146093.tsv does not exist: 'SRR1146093.tsv'`. Any ideas why?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to append the directory when reading. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and fix! I got another error now `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: I made some changes, you can try it again

Comment: I still get the same error, unfortunately, plus something new. `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: ........ KeyError: 'tpm'
`

Comment: This is probably a result of the data not being in the expect format somewhere, I added code to pinpoint this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230235/discussion-between-albert-and-rina).